# How to do the operation every 5 seconds netty (Server)

Tags: java, netty

I previously worked at workerman php to create a websocket server, but since I often work on java, I decided to study netty, I would like to know how to send a hello message to all users every 5 seconds, in workerman this is achieved by timers.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netty every [EventLoop](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/EventLoop.html) extends [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which means you could schedule a task to run every 5 seconds like this:

```java
Channel ch = ...;
ch.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```